# counting lattice paths with turns

Tags: combinatorics

I want to count words weighted by the number of "turns".

Pascal's triangle counts words of length $n$ with $k$ elements as explained in the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) :

$$(x+y)^n = \sum x^k y^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}$$

These are the generating function for the words in $\{ 0,1\}^n$.  I would like to count the number of instances of `01` or `10` in those words.

For example, if n = 3

```
xxx - 0

xxy - 1  xyx - 2  yxx - 1

xyy - 1  yxy - 2  yyx - 1

yyy - 0
```

Is there a formula for $\boxed{\sum_{w \in \{0,1\}^n} x^{\# 0(w)}y^{ \# 1(w)} q^{\# turns(w)} } $ ?  Also, points if you can explain what this object is called.

Comment: possibly: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477982/counting-bit-flips?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The formula is given by:

$$\dfrac{(x+y+\sqrt{4xyq^2+x^2+y^2-2xy})^{n} + (x+y-\sqrt{4xyq^2+x^2+y^2-2xy})^{n}}{2^{n}}$$

When $q=1$, this reduces to the usual binomial formula, $(x+y)^{n}$. We can derive this as follows.

Let $A_{n}(x,y,q)$ be your sum, but only over those $w$ that end in a $0$. Likewise, let $B_{n}(x,y,q)$ be your sum, but only over $w$ that end in a $1$. Clearly, the quantity we are interested in is $A_{n}(x,y,q) + B_{n}(x,y,q)$.

Now, note that a string of length $n+1$ is either: a) a string of length $n$ that ends in a $0$, followed by a $0$, b) a string of length $n$ that ends in a $1$, followed by a $0$, c) a string of length $n$ that ends in a $0$, followed by a $1$, or d) a string of length $n$ that ends in a $1$, followed by a $0$. In cases b and c, the number of turns is one more than in our original $n$-bit long string, while in cases a and d, the number of turns is the same as in our original $n$-bit long string. We therefore have (writing $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ as short for $A_{n}(x,y,q)$ and $B_{n}(x,y,q)$ respectively):

\begin{eqnarray*}
A_{n+1} &=& xA_{n} + xqB_{n} \\
B_{n+1} &=& yqA_{n} + yB_{n}
\end{eqnarray*}

These recurrence relations inspire us to examine the matrix

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
x & xq \\
yq & y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_1q \\
B_1q & B_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

It's straightforward to note that

$$M \begin{bmatrix}
A_n & A_nq \\
B_nq & B_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{n+1} & A_{n+1}q \\
B_{n+1}q & B_{n+1} \end{bmatrix}$$

and therefore that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A_n & A_nq \\
B_nq & B_n \end{bmatrix} = M^{n}$$

It follows that $A_n + B_n = \mathrm{Tr}(M^n) = \lambda_1^n + \lambda_2^{n}$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $M$. Computing these eigenvalues, we get the formula above.

I'm not sure what this object is called, but I would be very surprised if it has not been studied before.